# How can I tell if a list or function approaches infinite?

Tags: python, limit

I am trying to make a function that returns True if a list/function goes to infinite. Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain with an example?

Comment: An example function takes x as an argument, and returns x**2. I pass this function, or the list generated by the function (1,4,9,16...) as a parameter to another function, which will return True because the function/list continues to increase to infinite. Something that goes 1, 1.5, 1.75... should return False because it has a limit of 2.

Comment: @pengowen123 I'm not sure it's possible to do it for a list of values as opposed to a function, but checkout my answer for functions. It seems like it'd be too difficult to deduce the pattern behind an arbitrary list...

Answer (score 3):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

This is actually somewhat paradoxical a question. You are asking if you can potentially solve the halting problem in python. If a list or function goes to infinite that means it never returns, that is the only way you know. If the function never returns you can never determine whether or not it is never returning. So if you are right, you never find out. Otherwise it'll return.

That said, if you are looking for values closing to a bound. Create a cutoff point for a value acceptably close to that bound. Once you've hit that value you are assuming you've reached a fair distance.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about mathematical limits and whether a given function goes to infinity, then you can checkout [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html):

```
>>> from sympy import Symbol, limit, oo
>>> x = Symbol("x")
>>> limit(x**2, x, oo)
oo
```

Comment: I have a function that takes inputs x and n and generates a list based off of n. It returns the element of the list with x as an index. I can use sympy's limit(), but it only takes an expression. The function generates a list following this rule: each element of the list is the previous element squared, plus n. The function works, but I had difficulties when calling it as a parameter inside the limit() function.